Effect of high voltage electric field on the motion of charged particles in an isolated tube
Please refer to the image for a visualization of the schematic.
I feel I am trapped at this stage. I am trying to understand the following:
In a closed container, charged particles are moving from the cathode (-) to the anode (+) at low supply voltage, in the range of nearly 50V. If I apply an additional supply of high voltage (~10kV) with a common cathode (-), and a separated yet closeby anode (+), will the electric field of the high voltage supply have any effect on the motion (velocity, acceleration, direction) of the charged particles in the tube?


You need some description of the geometry of the anode(s). Are they solid? Perforated? Hollow? Also, is the tube an insulator, and if so, is there a route for electric field from HV through it?

The anodes are solid structures. SS plates to be exact. They are separated by an acrylic (PMMA) sheet - 2mm thick. The tube is an insulator. I understand the dielectric properties will limit the electric field to pass through.

50V is close enough to 0V that we can ignore it.  Then we get this geometry:

Green is ground, red is "hot", and tan is epoxy resin (ballpark close enough).
Fed into a simple field solver like ATLC or ATLC2, we get a field plot (cyan intensity = potential, normalized to (0, 255, 255) = 10kV):

With equipotential lines,

This assumes a prismatic construction, whereas I suppose your geometry might be rotationally symmetric, for which the voltage in the tube will be lower I think.  Or other geometries inbetween, for which a 3D field solver will be best.  So this is just for example.
You might find QuickField more convenient, for which there is a free, limited (student) version available, which should be able to handle the cylindrical case with ease.

Thanks for this Tim!

Cheers -- consider upvoting and/or selecting as answer; it's the currency that keeps this site running.


If I apply an additional supply of high voltage (~10kV) with a common cathode (-), and a separated yet closeby anode (+), will the electric field of the high voltage supply have any effect on the motion (velocity, acceleration, direction) of the charged particles in the tube?

The final velocity of the electrons when they hit the low voltage plate will be the same with or without the high voltage plate being present. This is is because the electric potential difference between the source and target plate is unaffected by the presence of the high voltage plate behind the low voltage target plate.
Although the final velocity of the electrons will be the same in either scenario, the transit time, or time of flight of the electrons will   (probably, I think) be different between the two scenarios.
I will assume that there are no conductive materials nearby other than what is shown in the diagram. I will also assume the distance between the source and target plate is large compared to their diameters.
In a capacitor, where the plate area is very large relative to their separation distance, the electric field is fairly uniform between the plates. This is not the case when the plates are far apart relative to their size. On the latter case, the electric field is strongest near the plates and is less strong near the midpoint between them. (Incidentally the internet, which is swamped with AI answers at the moment says the exact opposite, i.e. that the electric field strength is highest at their midpoint, which is not true for oppositely charged plates.
A consequence of this electric field strength profile is that electrons will accelerate quite a bit leaving the source, accelerate less in the middle, and the rate of acceleration will pick up again as they near the target.
What happens when the high voltage plate is added to the mix? First we need to consider the charge distribution. The addition of the high positive voltage plate will increase the negative charge on the source. This will increase the initial acceleration of the electrons. The high voltage plate will cause a decrease in the positive charge in the target plate, in fact, probably giving it a net negative charge. Don't be fooled by the plate being positive with respect to "ground". Our choice of  what constitutes ground potential is arbitrary and could just as well be the target plate. So the rate of acceleration will not be as high as the electrons approach the target plate compared to the scenario with no high voltage plate. Actually, the rate of acceleration will (I think) decrease compared to the midpoint, and I believe the electrons will actually decrease as they approach a net negativity charged target plate.
As the velocity profile will change with the presence or absence of the high voltage plate, I expect (but math is sometimes unintuitive) that the time of flight will also change.

Will the high electric field from the high voltage supply not affect the charges at all?

The velocity profile will change. See my edit.

Okay. Thanks for the perspective. Will research more on this.
